# No depurador do Google Crhome para JavaScript, tem como Pular alguns arquivos? Como o "Angular.js"

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, debug

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Tipo, preciso debugar com F10 ou F11, mas antes de uma função para outra, já chama esses arquivos, tipo o da imagem abaixo. 
Tem que como marcar que quero pular eles?

Comment: como você está no localhost acredito que tenha acesso ao código fonte, se você escrever lá "debugger;" nas linhas em que você quer parar, ele irá parar como se tivesse um breakpoint

Comment: No Google-Chrome eu consigo debugar;. Só que ele segue o debug nesses arquivos de configurações, que não estão com o código. Quero pular esses arquivos.

Comment: opa, beleza, entendi errado, já vou responder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No canto superior direito, próximo ao fechar existe um mais opções (3 pontinhos), ao clicar nele vai aparecer uma opção chamada settings, conforme imagem:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Em settings existe uma opção chamada Blackboxing, conforme imagem:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Clicando ali, vai existir uma opção chamada "Add patern", ai você coloca a url em questão que você quer ignorar, ou uma expressão regular.

Comment: Deu certo para os arquivos principais.

Mas ainda abre os VM???? (VM93199)

Para esses sem .extenção  tem alguma solução????

Comment: baseado nessa resposta aqui eu creio que não, Rebeca, é algo pedido ja faz um tempo pela comunidade
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29897750/is-it-possible-to-blackbox-all-vm-scripts-in-chrome-debugger